# Sass check if variable is passed to mixin

Tags: variables, sass

Lets say I have a mixin with default values

```
$default: 1;

@mixin test($p : $default) {
    @if () {
        // Do something if $p was 4passed?
    } @else {
        // Do something if $p was not passed?
    }

}
```

If I was to call the mixin like so, two different was:

```
@include test(); // A
@include test(1);  // B
```

Is there a way I can tell the difference between the default **(A)**, and the one that's overwriting the default **(B)**?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Your mixin would work if you modify it a tiny bit (as you actually need to pass the parameter in question to the `@if` directive. And you would want to default the parameter to `null` or `false`, which would mean that nothing was passed).

```js
@mixin test($p: null) {
    @if ($p) {
        /* Do something if $p was passed */
    } @else {
        /* Do something if $p was not passed */
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9803199)

If you want to set a different value as the default, then you just need to check for that specific value in the if statement (e.g. "do something if `$p` is set to the default value"). Here how you would do this by setting the default from a variable, like you do in your example. However, this will not differentiate between "*no argument passed*" and "*passed value equals default value*".

```js
@mixin test($p: $default) {
    @if ($p == $default) {
      /* Do something if $p is set to $default */
    } @else {
      /* Do something else if $p is not $default */
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9803569)

But of corse you can combine both approaches ... check if something is passed to `$p` (to do different things if passed or not), and if nothing is passed set `$p`'s value to default.

```js
@mixin test($p: null) {
    @if ($p) {
      /* Do something if argument passed */
    } @else {
      /* Do something else if no argument passed. Set $p to default. */
      $p: $default;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9805178)

This should now work for everything but the boolean value of `false`, as `null` and `false` both validate to `false` with the `@if` directive. So to allow passing `false` as an argument value you would need to use a more specific expression. For example:

```js
...
    @if ($p != null) {
...
```

[**DEMO**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9805993)

And voilà, this should do the trick - unless you, for some reason, want to pass `null` as an argument. Then you need to use something else as the default, like a string that is extremely unlikely to be passed as an argument, e.g. `"no arguments have been passed"` =)

[**DEMO**](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9806598)