# SASS mixing for CSS animations

Tags: css, sass

I am fairly new to sass, but I am trying to wrap my head around creating useful mixins.

I am trying to create a basic mixing for the `transition` property that will include fallbacks for older browsers with prefixes.

I was trying to use something like this:

```
@mixin transition($property, $duration, $timing-function, $delay) {
    -webkit-transition: $property, $duration, $timing-function, $delay;
    -moz-transition: $property, $duration, $timing-function, $delay;
    -o-transition: $property, $duration, $timing-function, $delay;
    transition: $property, $duration, $timing-function, $delay;
}
```

But that obviously doesn't provide prefixes, so I was trying to do something like `-webkit-transition: -webkit-$property, $duration, $timing-function, $delay;`, but that doesn't seem to work either.

How would I go about creating a mixing with vendor prefixes *in the variable*?

Comment: You could always have a look at how compass has done it: https://github.com/Compass/compass/blob/stable/core/stylesheets/compass/css3/_transition.scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `@if` statements within my mixin, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678065/sass-check-if-variable-is-passed-to-mixin).

In my particular case I was worried about the `transform` property and as it is 2017 when this question is being answered, I no longer need all of those previous vendor prefixes; [just -webkit](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

Here is the mixin:

```
@mixin transition($property, $duration, $timing-function, $delay) {
  @if ($property == 'transform') {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform $duration $timing-function $delay;
    transition: -webkit-transform $duration $timing-function $delay;
    transition: transform $duration $timing-function $delay;
    transition: transform $duration $timing-function $delay, -webkit-transform $duration $timing-function $delay;
  } @else {
    -webkit-transition: $property $duration $timing-function $delay;
    transition: $property $duration $timing-function, $delay;
  }
}
```

Using it like this:

```
div {
  color: red;
  @include transition(transform, 500ms, ease, 0);
}
```

Will compile to this:

```
div {
  color: red;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease 0;
  transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease 0;
  transition: transform 500ms ease 0;
  transition: transform 500ms ease 0, -webkit-transform 500ms ease 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`-webkit-transition: -webkit-$property, $duration, $timing-function, $delay;`,

try

`-webkit-transition: unquote('-webkit-' + $property) , $duration, $timing-function, $delay;`

But in this instance, you'd really be better off using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) which has some very well written mixins for common cases such as this.